# React not passing props to children?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the data from this axios call into a child component, Hero. Despite having passed down the props and made a successful axios call it won't actually make it into the Hero div.

When I console.log on the child component it claims to have the data but then fails to push it to the champions array so I can't use it. Any ideas?

Edit:

I'll add in here that I do have react-router installed in this project however this data is being passed around across one "view" and not multiple pages.

This is the parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './assets/stylesheets/screen.css';
import Hero from './Hero';
import Info from './Info';


class Home extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = { champions: [] };

}

 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(
     'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/gasulliv/pose-
references/pins/?access_token=AQjW6hDdAF0egwEesZA6oJbqP0XQFQ-
 m6_jg2RpErKPqdSA7cQAAAAA&limit=100&fields=id%2Clink%2Cnote%2
Curl%2Coriginal_link%2Cimage').then(champions => {
    this.setState({ champions });
    console.log(champions);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <div>
    <Hero champions = {this.state.champions} />
    <Info />
  </div>
);
  }
}

export default Home;
```

And this is child component (at this console log I get two answers, one claiming it has the data and another claiming it does not):

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';


import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/stylesheets/screen.css';



const Hero = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
return (

    <div className = "jumbotron kindred">
        <Header />
        <div className = "textHolder">{ props.champions.length }</div>
    </div>

    )
}

export default Hero;
```

[image]

Comment: I think axios returns the response object which has all sorts of information, ```statusCode``` etc, you may want to update axios ```.then``` call to this: ```axios.get("...url").then(response => { this.setState({ champions: response.data }); });```

Comment: That URL is returning a `400 Bad Request`

Comment: I get what you're coming from but it's still no good. It's claiming it's there and then ditching the data again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the data in the data key **response.data**

Try the following.

```
axios.get('https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/gasulliv/pose-references/pins/?access_token=AQjW6hDdAF0egwEesZA6oJbqP0XQFQ-m6_jg2RpErKPqdSA7cQAAAAA&limit=100&fields=id%2Clink%2Cnote%2Curl%2Coriginal_link%2Cimage')
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({
        champions: response.data
    })
})
.catch((error) => {
    // Do something with the error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help but it turns out the issue had to do with the fact that I had the router installed. Likely I just need to pass that data around through the router instead of the pages.

Kudos for the help!

Comment: based on the logs its showing `response.data` and the props in Hero is an object not an array, are you sure you are going deep enough and there is not another key in `response.data` ? This issue shouldn't have anything to do with router since the components are not present.  Usually API's don't return arrays in data its usually JSON, so the data may be under another key of champions `this.setState({
        champions: response.data.( look for extra key and apply here)
    })`

Comment: This is a good point. I'll try and search through the object again.